# Python timer that doesn't pause the whole program

Tags: python, tkinter, time, timer

I'm trying to make a mode for a simple game where you catch items as they fall down using tkinter.

In this mode, you have 60 seconds to catch as many items as you can. All the timer methods I've tried pause the whole program

...tried using an empty label, but the .after pauses the whole program

```
timerlabel = tkinter.Label(text="")
def timer():
    global t, timerdisplay
    while t > 0:
        t -= 1
        timerlabel.after(1000)
        c.delete(timerdisplay)
        timerdisplay = c.create_text(200, 12, text=t)
        c.update()
```

any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to pass a function to `.after()`; something to call once the time is up. For example: `timerlabel.after(1000, some_func)`.

Comment: And don't delete/recreate the label each time.  `timerdisplay.config( text=t )` will update the existing control.

Comment: You need to use threading

Comment: @GabeMorris -- no, they don't.  Threading is not the answer for a once-a-second timer, and you can't update the UI from a thread.  Events are the answer, using `.after()`.

Comment: @GabeMorris: they definitely don't need threading for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the better way to do it, specifically because `after(n)` freezes the program for the given time period. Create a function that accepts a number and displays that number. Then, it subtracts one and then reschedules itself to run one second in the future until the number becomes zero.

```
def timer(t):
    global timerdisplay
    c.delete(timerdisplay)
    timerdisplay = c.create_text(200, 12, text=t)
    if t >= 1:
        c.after(1000, timer, t-1)
timer(timerdisplay, 10)
```

To optimize this, you can pass in the canvas item along with the number. You can also just reconfigure the text item rather than deleting and restoring it.

```
def timer(timerdisplay, t):
    c.itemconfigure(timerdisplay, text=t)
    if t >= 1:
        c.after(1000, timer, timerdisplay, t-1)
timerdisplay = c.create_text(200, 12)
timer(timerdisplay, 10)
```